# What kind of audio captcha should I use against cold calling?

Tags: phone

Having a landline is starting to turning to be constantly harassed by cold callers these days.
So I’m thinking about making incoming calls landing on a voicemail controlled by [a custom computer script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language) where my phone would only ring after the audio captcha is successfully solved.

But of course, the problem is they are humans from low‑income countries most of the time, not bots. So **since I’m expecting calls only from guys working in ɪᴛ,** I thought of something they typically can’t afford : a fast cell phone since the applications they can use on their work computers are restricted.
In that case, I’m thinking about something like :

> If this call **is important**, and in order to prove its aim is not commercial, please dial the last 5 digits of `[big random number]` factorial followed by the # key.

But then, the problem is a genuine caller might not have the idea to use [cuda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) or [OpenCl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL), in order to solve the problem efficiently on high‑end hardware.

**So what kind of better captcha like challenge which can be solved over voicemail I should use ?**
Rules : every generated text can be turned to speech and anything that can be programmed is possible, but the foreign low‑income worker from a company illegally spoofing the original phone number needs to be disrupted.

Comment: Background : I had an Adblock style system in the past. But the government set up harsh laws against call calling so most companies started to illegally spoof their phone number : if you try to call back the caller, you will typically land on the line used by an individual from the state official phone book.

Comment: What proportion of genuine callers are you willing to lose?

Comment: The comments under my answers have completely muddied the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @motosubatsu I agree to lose calls about time of the day. I don’t want to lose calls about `relative passed away` or I `definitely want to do business with you`. That is, if the matter is really important, they will solve the challenge.

Comment: @WeatherVane no it’s you who supposed there are other way than using a captcha challenge for the problem. If I say so, it is.

Comment: So are you trying to solve a specific task that has been set for you, by others? This is a hack site: the idea is that you get offered solutions to a problem, which is to remove spam callers.

Comment: @WeatherVane such is less a problem with an apprenticeship.

Comment: If both of those answers aren't acceptable to you and cause a lengthy discussion, you need to clarify your question. How many spam calls and how many "hiring calls" or whatever are you expecting? And please keep in mind that foreign low-income workers aren't stupid savages, but intelligent people doing their thakless jobs. Your last paragraph gives off *really not good* vibes.

Comment: `aren't stupid savages, but intelligent people doing their thakless jobs` Yes I know. But it’s the wage that defines what you buy not who you are, hence the original idea which requires a very high end graphic card. The question is narrowed to `So what kind of better captcha like challenge which can be solved over voicemail I should use ?` not `How to block cold callers` in general.

Comment: Long story short, you can't create a perfect filter for real humans that doesn't involve a password or key or your own judgement, so if you need to accept calls from people with whom you have no way of communicating beforehand, this is impossible imo. Or just accept that there will be cases where your security through obscurity system is defeated (just make sure it's false positives, not negatives).

Comment: @LukeSawczak the example of the question is a wage filter, I m not sure there s no better challenges, while not perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Asking a clever question not only risks losing genuine callers, but is insulting, as if to say *"If you are too stupid to answer my question I won't talk to you."*

I suggest you set up a fake switchboard and give out a PIN to your known contacts as if it is an extension number:

- My number is 01234567890 extension 1234.

Your script detects the PIN and routes the call to your phone if correct. Otherwise a message states:

- Please enter my extension number, otherwise enter 6789 to activate voicemail.

which then does silently activate voicemail if that code is entered. In effect, you have a public PIN 6789 and a private one 1234.

This should get rid of most spam callers, allow people to leave messages, or speak to you, with minimal inconvenience or anything off-key.

Comment: The problem is I’m looking for an apprenticeship. I need to receive calls from people I never talked to before. Don’t need a voice mail for whitelisting phone numbers, as even the pstn allows to block calls by id. A point is most bosses think an apprentice in ɪᴛ still in college is unable to write and configure such voicemail scripts so this is a proof of my habilities more than something unusual.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood. I am not suggesting you keep any whitelist, but tell people your phone number is 0123456789 extn 1234. The spammer won't know that when dialling random numbers. Your script does, so routes through any caller who uses the fake "extension" number. It isn't at all unusual to have a business number with an extension. It looks perfectly normal.

Comment: If you are looking for an apprenticeship, how do you think callers will react to being asked a question by a machine that they have to go away and look up before you condescend to speak to them? It's like *you* are interviewing *them*, it's the wrong way round.

Comment: `I think you have misunderstood. I am not suggesting you keep any whitelist, but tell people your phone number is 0123456789 extn 1234.` which is the same as asking those people their phone numbers and whitelisting them.

Comment: `If you are looking for an apprenticeship, how do you think callers will react to being asked a question by a machine that they have to go away and look up before you condescend to speak to them?` As I said, the reaction would be mixed. If you simply say your are able to do something like this virtually no bosses would believe you (no master degree ? impossible !). But actually doing it is proving you’re a good fit for the job versus other applicants who will typically seek technical help every 20min‒30min.

Comment: No, when you are looking for your job in IT you say "**my** phone number is *that*" When they call, the number you have told them will be routed through automatically. Anyone who has not been given the number (and extension), i.e. is dialling at random, won't get past your script.

Comment: You've completely switched the question you are asking. It now seems to have nothing to do with spam callers but impressing employers when applying for a job in IT? I am lost.

Comment: `You've completely switched the question you are asking. It now seems to have nothing to do with spam callers but impressing employers when applying for a job in IT? I am lost.` primarily against spam, bosses who just found my public profile might be impressed so such captcha like challenges wouldn’t be a problem for them.

Comment: So: the objective **isn't** to suppress spam, but to impress "bosses who found your profile"?

Comment: The main objective is to suppress spam while still allowing a class of people I never contacted before to reach me (bosses).

Comment: I that case, why can't you just publicise the phone number with extension? Is it because you want to **show off** to bosses that *if* they had been a spam caller you would have caught them? This gets stranger by the minute.

Comment: If `I publicise the phone number with extension` spam companies and their crawl bots will be able to figure the trick so it would inneffective if it’s not private.

Comment: That's for email addresses. For phone numbers they just make random calls by machine, and when one gets answered it is patched to a human operator (if available).

Comment: Anyway good luck with the job hunt. I am sure the world is going to beat a path to your door.

Answer (score 2):

I have a voicemail machine on the landline which I leave active, and I can see caller ID too (unless blocked). If I recognise it as a usual caller, I pick up. Otherwise voicemail kicks in and I can hear them speak, and if I want to talk to them I pick up and cancel the voicemail, replying as if I only just caught the call. If they have already hung up, I can call back if I want to.

So, you could keep it simple and record a message to say, for example:

- Good day, please state your name and your company name as this call is filtered electronically, before being routed to me.

The 'filter' being you, and you pick up if you like what you hear.

---

Hack #2. Suppose you are in UK and the harassment is coming from another phone area. Ask for the *first* 4 digits of the phone number to be dialled in again for your script. If it is an international call, they won't be the same as from a domestic call. If they rumble that, they might not realise that UK domestic phone numbers begin with a 0 which is omitted when dialling from outside the area.

Comment: But in my case, I need to not call back many times. And with the number of useless calls I m receiving, I would still fill bothered too many times. And again, those companies are spoofing phone numbers of mainland users.

Comment: In that case, try my hack #2, asking for the first few digits, which you also program into your filter script.

Comment: In France, all numbers have the same length. Those foreign companies takes care to call you using a spotofed number of the same region or even city.

Comment: I meant, the first few digit of *your* number, not theirs. If it's an international call and they include the international dialing code, it won't be acceptable to the script. UK numbers are all the same length too *except* when called internationally, which they might not realise. The spam callers I get are so stupid they call me multiple times even when they got a definite "no." Quite often too, the spoof ID hasn't enough digits to be a real phone number, so you could check that too.

Comment: *But in my case, I need to not call back many times.* Don't call them back then. How is that an objection? If you turn the the voicemail volume down low, you'll soon learn to ignore it and your ear will pick out only what you need to pay attention to.

Comment: And if the call comes from the boss ? You understand I need a system which needs to makes legitimate calls to always pass.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand this shift in angle. Why will a call from "the boss" be any different? How will "the boss" react to being asked to go away and look up the answer to a nerdy question?